# Unable to set endpoint using the Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli

I used docker-machine with Azure as the driver to spin up a VM. I then deployed a simple nginx test container on to the host. My issue is that when I try to set and endpoint I am getting the following error:

```
azure vm endpoint create huldra 80 32769
info:    Executing command vm endpoint create
+ Getting virtual machines
+ Reading network configuration
+ Updating network configuration
error:   Parameter 'ConsoleScreenshotBlobUri' should not be set.
info:    Error information has been recorded to /Users/ryan/.azure/azure.err
error:   vm endpoint create command failed
```

When I look at the error log it pretty much repeats what the console said `Parameter 'ConsoleScreenshotBlobUri' should not be set.`

Here are my docker and azure environment details:

```
❯ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.10.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 21
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-18-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.636 GiB
Name: huldra
ID: PHUY:JRE3:DOJO:NNWO:JBBH:42H2:56ZO:HVSB:MZDE:QLOI:GO6F:SCC5
WARNING: No swap limit support
Labels:
 provider=azure

~/Projects/dockerswarm master*
❯ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
ce51127b2bb8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->443/tcp   machinenginx

❯ azure --version
0.9.17 (node: 5.8.0)

❯ azure vm list
info:    Executing command vm list
+ Getting virtual machines
data:    Name    Status     Location  DNS Name             IP Address
data:    ------  ---------  --------  -------------------  -------------
data:    huldra  ReadyRole  West US   huldra.cloudapp.net  x.x.x.x
info:    vm list command OK
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error.